# How can I do `pushMatrix` or `popMatrix` of GL in CoreGraphics?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, core-graphics, transform

In GL, I have used some kind of this stuff,

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef();

// Do something

glPopMatrix();
```

To make and work in a derived coordinate system.
How can I archive this functionality in CoreGraphics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you’re talking about OpenGL ES, in which case you should [go and check out this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918232/opengl-es-2-0-and-glpushmatrix-glpopmatrix).

If you’re really talking about CoreGraphics check out `CGContextSaveGState()` and `CGContextRestoreGState()`.

Comment: Is `CGContextSaveGState()` stackable like `pushMatrix()`?