# glPushMatrix() & glPopMatrix() throw GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

i try to draw a waveform from the incoming iphone microphone stream. The extraction of the data was no problem an the drawing works fine. Only when I use the OpenGL Exception Breakpoint xcode throws exceptions at `glPushMatrix() & glPopMatrix()`with the code `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. I searched the internet for some more informations, but the only thing that i found was this:

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glPushMatrix or glPopMatrix is executed between the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd.
```

i dont use the commands glBegin oder glEnd, because of that this doesn't help me. Any ideas? What is the problem here? i draw the stuff like this:

```
- (void)drawPlotWithView:(GLKView*)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _plotVBO);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(XOAudioPlotGLPoint), NULL);

[self.baseEffect prepareToDraw];
glPushMatrix();
self.baseEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeXRotation(0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, _plotGraphSize);
glPopMatrix();

[self.baseEffect prepareToDraw];
glPushMatrix();
self.baseEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeXRotation(M_PI);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, _plotGraphSize);
glPopMatrix();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

the initialization ist like this:

```
self.baseEffect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
self.baseEffect.useConstantColor = GL_TRUE;
self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60;


if (![EAGLContext currentContext]) {
    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
} else {
    self.context = [EAGLContext currentContext];
}

if (!self.context) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
} else {
    EAGLContext.currentContext = self.context;
}

GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
view.context = self.context;
view.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;
glGenBuffers(1, &_plotVBO);
glLineWidth(2.0f);
```

Comment: Where in the ES 2.0 documentation did you find entries for `glBegin()/glEnd()`?

Comment: nowhere, thats why i'm so confused! Only found this: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml

Comment: I believe that was a rhetorical question by @genpfault. Those calls do not exist in ES 2.0.

Comment: I knew but that was the only thing I've found...

Comment: [The opengl ES 2.0 Spec](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/) does not list glPushMatrix nor glPopMatrix. I do not know the ES version and it seems strange to me, but maybe Push/PopMatrix is not supported? Also, are you sure the debugger/xcode gives the correct lines for the exceptions?

Comment: in the OpenGL Analyser i got this: http://s14.directupload.net/images/140908/n67umqxw.png

Comment: I do not know this Analyser, but i've seen more than one similar program giving strange results, mostly since their developers can't keep up with the dev speed of opengl or due to issues with old compatibility and new gl calls. So the question might be - does it work anyway with your model transforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` refer to the built-in matrix stack from the fixed-function OpenGL pipeline -- that functionality isn't in OpenGL ES 2.0.

However, the way that you're using it looks like it's not really doing anything, and what you are doing is in the wrong order. Drawing with `GLKBaseEffect` takes three steps:

1. Set the modelview and projection matrices via properties on your `GLKBaseEffect` instance. There's no "current matrix" or "matrix mode" implicit state like there is in GLES 1.x; just explicitly named and separately stored properties on `GLKBaseEffect`. (You're already doing this with the lines where you set `self.baseEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix`.)
2. Call `prepareToDraw` on the `GLKBaseEffect` instance. This binds the matrices, textures, and other state you've set in `GLKBaseEffect` for use by the shaders that class generates for you. (You're doing this before setting each matrix, so the matrices you're setting aren't taking effect when you want.)
3. After all that, perform an OpenGL draw command (`glDrawArrays`, `glDrawElements`, etc.) to draw with the state you've set.

The one additional thing you might think about is whether you've (elsewhere) set a different modelview matrix on your `baseEffect` and are using it for other draw calls. In that case, you might want to save the current matrix before drawing with a different matrix, then restore it afterward. A matrix stack is useful for that, and GLKit provides one in the [`GLKMatrixStack`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrixStack/index.html) type and related functions. But if these are your only draw calls with that effect, or your other calls create a matrix from scratch like these ones do, there's no need to save/restore.

Comment: I must actually only exchange the order of the commands and remove the glPushMatrix () & glPopMatrix () stuff? i tried it, but yet the waveform doesn't work anymore -.- maybe you can give me some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing my research on the topic, the answer seems to be that OpenGL ES 2.0 indeed does not support matrix stack or push/pop, see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2918262/3967585)

Comment: You may want to say "OpenGL ES 2.0", because full OpenGL still supports them when using the compatibility profile.